# Prevent Sass framework variable collisions

Tags: import, sass, scope

Is there a way that I could import multiple framework Sass files in a way that each framework will use its own variables without the variables of one framework overriding/colliding with the variables of the other while I would still be able to access the variables of one or both of those frameworks in subsequent styles as needed?

For example:

framework-a-variables.scss:

```
$border-color: green !default;
```

framework-a-box.scss:

```
.box-a { border: 1px solid $border-color; }
```

framework-b-variables.scss:

```
$border-color: red !default;
```

framework-b-box.scss:

```
.box-b { border: 1px solid $border-color; }
```

app-styles.scss:

```
@import 'framework-a-variables';
@import 'framework-a-box';
@import 'framework-b-variables';
@import 'framework-b-box';
```

This will result in an element with a `box-b` class having a green border due to how Sass variable declarations and the !default keyword work. Likewise, if I wanted to use $border-color as defined by framework-b-variables.scss in, say, button-styles.scss, I wouldn't be able to.

I have tried using placeholder selectors to scope the Sass imports so that the variables initialized by each framework are scoped to be used only by the other imported files of that framework. This seems to scope the variables as desired, but none of the styles are compiled unless I extend the placeholder selector, but Sass requires that extend directives be used only within rules and I wouldn't want to increase the specificity of all my selectors just to achieve this.

```
%framework-a-scope {
  @import 'framework-a-variables';
  @import 'framework-a-box';
}

%framework-b-scope {
  @import 'framework-b-variables';
  @import 'framework-b-box';
}

@extend %framework-a-scope; // This is not allowed in Sass
@extend %framework-a-scope; // This is not allowed in Sass

html {
  @extend %framework-a-scope; // Wouldn't want do this
  @extend %framework-b-scope; // Wouldn't want do this
}
```

I have also tried using mixins to scope the Sass imports. I believe that mixins, unlike extends, can output rules without being nested within rules, but Sass does not allow import directives within control directives or mixins.

```
@mixin framework-a-scope() {
  @import 'framework-a-variables'; // This is not allowed in Sass
  @import 'framework-a-box'; // This is not allowed in Sass
}

@include framework-a-scope();
```

So, is there any way to achieve what I am looking to achieve? I don't mind having to explicitly import variables in specific scopes when needed, for example:

```
.my-custom-box-1 {
  @import 'framework-a-variables';
  border: 1px solid $border-color;
}

.my-custom-box-2 {
  @import 'framework-b-variables';
  border: 1px solid $border-color;
}
```

Comment: Why the `!default` keyword on both variables with same name? If you just remove those keywords the problem will be solved. Or at least just use it in the first declaration of `$border-color`.

Comment: @muecas Sorry if the examples were not clear. The framework-*.scss files represent 3rd-party framework files and, as such, I don't intend to change those variable assignments as that would entail editing the source code of the frameworks, which is a deal-breaker in my case.

Comment: And why are you including those files in a single scss file? Just to concatenate the result?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. I am using webpack, so as a workaround I have updated the JS module that was importing my main.scss file to now import framework-a.scss, then framework-b.scss, then main.scss. That way, each framework is compiled using its own variables, mixins, etc. Granted, shared class names will still collide, but I am not concerned about that issue for now. I am still able to import framework variables and mixins in the manner shown in my last code snippet in the OP, although there are some caveats, for example, the issue of not being able to nest an import in a mixin.